# What is the substitute for com.sun.tools after jdk 16?

Tags: java, lombok

I read some articles which teach how to implement Lombok. It mentions that lombok was implemented by JavacTrees, TreeMaker in the jdk package com.sun.tools like below:

```
import com.sun.source.tree.Tree;
import com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTrees;
import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Flags;
import com.sun.tools.javac.code.Type;
import com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeTranslator;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.*;

import javax.annotation.processing.*;
import javax.lang.model.SourceVersion;
import javax.lang.model.element.Element;
import javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement;
import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
import java.util.Set;

@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("com.example.lombok.MyGetter")
public class MyGetterProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private Messager messager;
    private JavacTrees javacTrees; 
    private TreeMaker treeMaker;
    private Names names;

    @Override
    public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        this.messager = processingEnv.getMessager();
        this.javacTrees = JavacTrees.instance(processingEnv);
        Context context = ((JavacProcessingEnvironment) processingEnv).getContext();
        this.treeMaker = TreeMaker.instance(context);
        this.names = Names.instance(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        Set<? extends Element> elementsAnnotatedWith = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyGetter.class);
        elementsAnnotatedWith.forEach(e -> {
            JCTree tree = javacTrees.getTree(e);
            tree.accept(new TreeTranslator() {
                @Override
                public void visitClassDef(JCTree.JCClassDecl jcClassDecl) {
                    List<JCTree.JCVariableDecl> jcVariableDeclList = List.nil();

                    for (JCTree jcTree : jcClassDecl.defs) {
                        if (jcTree.getKind().equals(Tree.Kind.VARIABLE)) {
                            JCTree.JCVariableDecl jcVariableDecl = (JCTree.JCVariableDecl) jcTree;
                            jcVariableDeclList = jcVariableDeclList.append(jcVariableDecl);
                        }
                    }

                    jcVariableDeclList.forEach(jcVariableDecl -> {
                        messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, jcVariableDecl.getName() + " has been processed");
                        jcClassDecl.defs = jcClassDecl.defs.prepend(makeGetterMethodDecl(jcVariableDecl));
                    });
                    super.visitClassDef(jcClassDecl);
                }
            });
        });
        return true;
    }

    private JCTree.JCMethodDecl makeGetterMethodDecl(JCTree.JCVariableDecl jcVariableDecl) {
        ListBuffer<JCTree.JCStatement> statements = new ListBuffer<>();
        // 生成表达式 例如 this.a = a;
        JCTree.JCExpressionStatement aThis = makeAssignment(treeMaker.Select(treeMaker.Ident(
                names.fromString("this")), jcVariableDecl.getName()), treeMaker.Ident(jcVariableDecl.getName()));
        statements.append(aThis);
        JCTree.JCBlock block = treeMaker.Block(0, statements.toList());


        JCTree.JCVariableDecl param = treeMaker.VarDef(treeMaker.Modifiers(Flags.PARAMETER),
                jcVariableDecl.getName(), jcVariableDecl.vartype, null);
        List<JCTree.JCVariableDecl> parameters = List.of(param);


        JCTree.JCExpression methodType = treeMaker.Type(new Type.JCVoidType());
        return treeMaker.MethodDef(treeMaker.Modifiers(Flags.PUBLIC),
                getNewMethodName(jcVariableDecl.getName()), methodType, List.nil(),
                parameters, List.nil(), block, null);

    }

    private Name getNewMethodName(Name name) {
        String s = name.toString();
        return names.fromString("get" + s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1, name.length()));
    }

    private JCTree.JCExpressionStatement makeAssignment(JCTree.JCExpression lhs, JCTree.JCExpression rhs) {
        return treeMaker.Exec(
                treeMaker.Assign(
                        lhs,
                        rhs
                )
        );
    }
}
```

However, com.sun.tools cannot be accessible after jdk 16. How is it implemented after jdk 16?

I try to find the source code of new version of Lombok but I only find the source code of the version below 1.18.20 of Lombok in github. The version below 1.18.20 of Lombok still use com.sun.tools to implement. As I know, after Lombok 1.18.20, it used another implementation.

How can I do that after jdk 16 without access of com.sun.tools?

Updates:
I read the new version of source code of Lombok. I saw it import the package as below:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassWriter;
import com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler;
import com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler;
import com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment;
import com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree.JCCompilationUnit;
import com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context;
```

but these package has already not been accessible after jdk 16. Why Lombok can still use them?

Comment: Where are you looking at GitHub, because https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok contains the source of the latest versions.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel but how Lombok do that

Answer (score 2):

[pom.xml](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/master/docker/maven/files/jdk-9/classpath/pom.xml) & [module-info.java](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/master/src/core9/module-info.java)

These two files will give you the answer.

He registered `jdk.compiler` in module-info

Also registered in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings> 
                <fork>true</fork>
                <compilerargs>
                    <arg>-Werror</arg>
                    <arg>-Xlint:all</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                    <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                </compilerargs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I had to use slightly different syntax to make it work: `<arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg><arg>--add-exports</arg><arg>jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>... etc `